# My photostream pics are gone after iOS 8 update

Tags: photo-stream, ios

I did the iOS8 update and prior to this my photostream had 700+ photos but I only had 200+ of those in my camera roll, I assumed they were backed up on my iCloud, however after the update I only have access to the 200 photos from the camera roll.

Where did my photostream of backed up pics go and how do I recover them ?

Comment: What hardware do you own? PC, Mac, iPhone, iPad? The photo stream lives in the cloud, so you could easily check what is there from another device to rule out a problem with your main device.

Answer (score 1):

In the photos app at the bottom are three options, Photos, Shared, and Albums.

Tap "photos". In the top left it probably shows "Collections", tap that to go back up to the collections, then tap "Years" to go back up to the top level. This will show all the photos on your device.

Comment: I get that, but I am still missing all the photos that were in my photo stream and backed up to the cloud, how do I recover them

Comment: All of your photos should be in the Collections or in the album "Recently Deleted" If you have an album named "Hidden" then they can also be there. If they are not in any of those places, restore you backup again.